# Display specific data from external website

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

Let's say this is the external website:

```
title
header
banner
content1
content2
footer
```

Now I want to know how to copy a specific part of the external website and paste it on my own like this:

```
my title
my header
my banner
my content
external content2
my footer
```

I only want to get the html code so I can make my own stylesheet for external content2

I hope this is clear enough.

I've tried using phps `file_get_html()`

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear on what you are attempting to do.  Remember you can only see html and javascript on someone else's web site. If you want to make a static copy of a web page including the cascading style sheets (CSS) and java scripts, open up the web page of interest on a browser (I'm thinking firefox) then use the browser tools to 'save the page as' and save it to your local hard drive.  With that save comes all the scripts and CSS files.

You can then look at the static code, look at the div classes and decide for yourself what CSS elements you are hoping to use for your site.

Recommend you study up on how css works (selector type element, selector type universal, selector type id declarations, and selector type class declarations)  Its highly possible the web site you are looking at is designed with 'div class=header   /div' declarations but not necessarily.

I think it would be rather difficult to scrape someone elses site with php, unless its one of your own, and you control what elements are there and in which sequence, CONSISTENTLY. Its possible to grab all html from someone else's site, then stubby pencil analyze it (with lots of if loops), but to get the css selector types to always match your css is not likely.

Oh, and the php code you will use for web site scraping is "$data = file_get_contents('url....... '

Good luck with it.